# Spring batch Job read from multiple sources

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-batch

How can I read items from multiples databases? I already know that is possible from files.
the following example works for read from multiples files

```
...
<job id="readMultiFileJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            commit-interval="1" />
    </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
...
<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:csv/inputs/domain-*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>
...
```

---

three beans like this.

```
<bean id="database2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="name" value="database2Reader" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <property name="sql" value="select image from object where image like '%/images/%'" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="sym.batch.ImagesRowMapper2" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you give more information about your situation?  
Like;  
-Do you read from same database type(MySQL, Oracle or DB2)?  
-Do you read same table from different database instance? If answer is no, how can you map your input to same object?

Comment: are MySQL with different tables, I just wanna take a String

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a ready-to-use component that perform what you ask; the only solution is to write a custom `ItemReader<>` that delegates to `JdbcCursorItemReader` (or to `HibernateCursorItemReader` or to any generic `ItemReader` implementation).
You need to prepare all necessary stuff (datasource, session, real database readers) and bind all delegated readers to your custom reader.

EDIT:
You need to simulate a loop using recusion of `ItemReader.read()` and mantain reader and delegates state across job restarts.

```
class MyItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>, ItemStream {
  private ItemReader[] delegates;
  private int delegateIndex;
  private ItemReader<T> currentDelegate;
  private ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext;

  public void setDelegates(ItemReader[] delegates) {
    this.delegates = delegates;
  }

  @BeforeStep
  private void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecutionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
  }

  public T read() {
    T item = null;
    if(null != currentDelegate) {
      item = currentDelegate.read();
      if(null == item) {
        ((ItemStream)this.currentDelegate).close();
        this.currentDelegate = null;
      }
    }
    // Move to next delegate if previous was exhausted!
    if(null == item && this.delegateIndex< this.delegates.length) {
      this.currentDelegate = this.delegates[this.currentIndex++];
      ((ItemStream)this.currentDelegate).open(this.stepExecutionContext);
      update(this.stepExecutionContext);
      // Recurse to read() to simulate loop through delegates
      item = read();
    }
    return item;
  }

  public void open(ExecutionContext ctx) {
    // During open restore last active reader and restore its state
    if(ctx.containsKey("index")) {
      this.delegateIndex = ctx.getInt("index");
      this.currentDelegate = this.delegates[this.delegateIndex];
      ((ItemStream)this.currentDelegate ).open(ctx);
    }
  }

  public void update(ExecutionContext ctx) {
    // Update current delegate index and state
    ctx.putInt("index", this.delegateIndex);
    if(null != this.currentDelegate) {
      ((ItemStream)this.currentDelegate).update(ctx);
    }
  }

  public void close(ExecutionContext ctx) {
    if(null != this.currentDelegate) {
      ((ItemStream)this.currentDelegate).close();
  }
}
```

---

```
<bean id="myItemReader" class=path.to.MyItemReader>
  <property name="delegates">
    <array>
      <ref bean="itemReader1"/>
      <ref bean="itemReader2"/>
      <ref bean="itemReader3"/>
    </array>
  </property>
</bean>
```

---

EDIT2: Remember to set property **name**; this is NECESSARY to let MyItemReader.read() works correctly

```
<bean id="itemReader1" class="JdbcCursorItemReader">
  <property name="name" value="itemReader1" />
  <!-- Set other properties -->
</bean>
```

Comment: from where this currentIndex is appearing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a simple workaround that may not be suitable to all cases, but will be useful in many:

Simply define:

- 2 readers, one for each database
- 2 steps
- one job that contains both 2 steps

The 2 steps are nearly identical, they reference the same processor and writer, but they have different readers. They will be called consecutively.

Whether this setup works will depend on the processor and writer (whether they still work correctly when called in different steps). In my case, it was sufficient to set `appendAllowed=true` to the writer, such that both steps can write to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a tricky way. If we assume that one is your mysql datasource's table is base and every row in that table corresponds other mysql datasource table's row(like a join tables which are in different datasources), you could do it in your batch job itemreader. Ex of this way;

Spring DataSource Configuration;

```
<bean id="mySqlDataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database1.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database1.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database1.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database1.password}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database1.validationQuery}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySqlDataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database2.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database2.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database2.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database2.password}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database2.validationQuery}"/>
</bean>
```

Your batch-job.xml

```
<bean id="multiDatasorceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource1" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="multiDatasourceRowMapper" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            SELECT * FROM xyz
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multiDatasourceRowMapper" class="yourpackage.MultiDatasourceRowMapper" scope="step">
    <property name="secondDataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource2" />
    <property name="secondSql">
        <value>
            SELECT * FROM abc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Your RowMapper looks like;

```
public class MultiDatasourceRowMapper implements RowMapper<String> {

    private DataSource secondDataSource;

    private String secondSql;

    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = secondDataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(secondSql); 

        // Do Something

        return "";
    }

    public void setSecondDataSource(DataSource secondDataSource) {
        this.secondDataSource = secondDataSource;
    }

    public void setSecondSql(String secondSql) {
        this.secondSql = secondSql;
    }

}
```