# Spring batch item reader reading from multiple databases

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have an `Item` object as below:

```
class Item{
   private String idProperty;
   private String prop1Db1;
   private String prop2Db1;
   private String prop1Db2;
   private String prop2Db2;

   // getters and setters here
  }
```

Now, for a given `idProperty`, two of the properties comes from one database, while other two properties comes from another database (as clear from the property names). The tables in both the databases have `idProperty` as the common property.

One approach I could take is read the first three properties from the first database. Pass the incomplete `Item` to a `Processor` and fire a query in the `Processor` to get other two properties to complete the `Item` before passing it to `Writer`.

However, for a huge number of records (millions), it will be a huge performance hit just with the number of queries I will have to fire in the `Processor`.

Is there any way to do it in the `Reader` itself ? A `Reader` which reads from two database simultaneously to create an `Item` before sending it to `Processor` and `Writer` ahead ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304364/spring-batch-job-read-from-multiple-database

Comment: @KarthikPrasad: No, its not a duplicate. The question you link reads same kinds of record from two databases, say a Book object. While in my case the properties of a single Book object is divided across two databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this answer as a 'workaround' because I think more elegant solutions are around the corner...
You should change your reader/processor/writer let them return a `List<Item>` instead of a single `Item` object; in this way in your processor you can fire a single query using the SQL `IN()` fetching `Item.idProperty` from processing `List<>`.
According to `List<>`'s size you can reduce the amount of fired queries.