# Multiple readers in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement to implement in Spring batch,I need to read from a file and from a DB ,the data needs to be processed and written to an email

I have gone through the spring batch documentation but was unable to find a CHUNKtasklet which would read data from multiple readers

SO essentially I have to read from 2 different sources of data(one from file and another from DB,each will need to have its own mapper)

Regards
Tar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring batch Job read from multiple database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304364/spring-batch-job-read-from-multiple-database)

Comment: Its all depends on, what is the relation between data in file and data in db, could you explain that bit more?

Answer (score 6):

I see two options depending on how the data is structured:

1. Spring Batch relies heavily on composition when building batch components.  One option would be to create a custom composite `ItemReader` that delegates to a other readers (ones Spring Batch provides or otherwise) and provides the logic to assemble a single object based on the results of those delegated `ItemReader`s.
2. You could use an `ItemReader` to provide the base information (say from a database) and use and `ItemProcessor` to enrich the item (say reading from a file).

Either of the above are normal ways to handle this type of input scenario.