# Spring Batch: Multiple Item Readers in a single step

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am a newbie in spring batch. The task I need to achieve in spring batch as follows:

1. Need to read some metadata from database.
2. Based on this metadata, I need to read some files.
3. After some processing, need to write those values from file to database.

My queries are the following:

a. For the 1st requirement, I needed to map the whole resultset to a single object, where Person related data are in 1 table and Pets related data are in another table and joined by person id.

```
public class PersonPetDetails {

    private String personName;
    private String personAddr;

    private int personAge;

    private List<Pet> pets;
```

For this I have written a custom Item reader which extends JdbcCursorItemReader.

```
public class CustomJDBCCusrorItemReader<T> extends JdbcCursorItemReader<T> {

    private ResultSetExtractor<T> resultSetExtractor;


    public void setResultSetExtractor(ResultSetExtractor<T> resultSetExtractor) {
        this.resultSetExtractor = resultSetExtractor;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
        Assert.notNull(getDataSource(), "DataSource must be provided");
        Assert.notNull(getSql(), "The SQL query must be provided");
        Assert.notNull(resultSetExtractor, "ResultSetExtractor must be provided");
    }


    @Override
    protected T readCursor(ResultSet rs, int currentRow) throws SQLException {      
        return resultSetExtractor.extractData(rs);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve my requirement? Or is there a much better way?

b. AFAIK, in spring batch there cannot be a step with just a reader, without a writer. Hence, I cannot call another set of reader in a different step of the Job. Then, how can I call multiple readers in a single step?

c. Also, based on some condition I may need to call a third set of Reader. How can I conditionally call a reader in a step?

Thanks for going through my post. I know it is long. Any help is much appreciated. Also, i guess an example code snippet would help me better understand the point. :)

Comment: My first advice is to divide your question to multiple questions because point a) b) and c) are totally unrelated.
a) can be resolved using delegation over extension
b) multiple reader can be used in certain circumstances (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304364/spring-batch-job-read-from-multiple-database, for example)
c) condition in SB are resolved using JobExecutionDecider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend as below

**High Level Design:**

1. Partitioner
   It will deal with list of persons. Note: there is not Pet data pulled at this point of time.
2. Reader
   It will get a list of Pet which are belong to a Person. Note: Reader will return a list of Pet specific to a Person only.
3. Processor
   Base on a Pet-Person you will process base on your requirement.
4. Writer
   Based on your requirement to write to DB.

**Low Level Code snippet:**

1. `Partitioner`

   ```
   public class PetPersonPartitioner implements Partitioner {

     @Autowired
     private PersonDAO personDAO;

     @Override
     public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

       Map<String, ExecutionContext> queue = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

       List<Person> personList = this.personDAO.getAllPersons();
       for (Person person : personList) {

         ExecutionContext ec = new ExecutionContext();
         ec.put("person", person);
         ec.put("personId", person.getId());

         queue.put(person.getId(), ec);
       }

     return queue;
     }
   }
   ```
2. `Reader`

   ```
   <bean id="petByPersonIdRowMapper" class="yourpackage.PetByPersonIdRowMapper" />

   <bean id="petByPesonIdStatementSetter" scope="step"
         class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter">
       <property name="parameters">
           <list>
               <value>#{stepExecutionContext['personId']}</value>
           </list>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```

> ```
> public class PetByPersonIdRowMapper implements RowMapper<PersonPetDetails> {
>     @Override
>     public BillingFeeConfigEntity mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
>         PersonPetDetails record = new PersonPetDetails();
>
>         record.setPersonId(rs.getLong("personId"));
>       record.setPetId(rs.getLong("petid");
>       ...
>       ...
> }
> ```

3. `Processor`
   You can continue working on each `PersonPetDetails` object.

Comment: I would like to have one PersonPetDetails object and based on that object I would have to read multiple files in subsequent step. Do you think a tasklet would be more suitable instead of a partitioner?