# Read and process multiple sources in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

Using spring batch, I want to read from a file and a database, join the data and write to a database. I see a lot of examples that explain reading from multiple files or table but not both. Is there a way i can do this? An example would be great! thanks.

Comment: Data retrieved from File and Data from Database are the same or different one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch Job read from multiple sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304364/spring-batch-job-read-from-multiple-sources)