# Read from multiple datasources, process and write in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing an application in spring boot with spring batch which has the following steps.

1. Read from db1
2. Read from db2
3. Process/Compare data
4. Write response to a file

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Well you define a good way of doing it, maybe check this to see how to code it. https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: It seems a pretty standard flow to implement with Spring Batch application. You can follow the Spring official tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch Job read from multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304364/spring-batch-job-read-from-multiple-sources)